# Multi threading in Modbus? How can send query at 500 ms keeping response time as 1 second?

Tags: c, serial-port, modbus, rs485

I have implemented MODBUS master slave communication. I have
implemented fun 6, 16 & 3. I set 1 minute as response time. Now
problem is that I want to send query at 500 ms. But because of this 1
second response time, I need to wait till 1 sec to send the second
query. How I can send query at every 500 ms keeping response time as 1
sec.

Is it possible to send new query, if we are still waiting for response of our previous query as well?

How to communicate with slower device over MODBUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 2.1 of the [*MODBUS over serial line specification and implementation guide V1.02*](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) where

> The master node initiates only one MODBUS transaction at the same
>   time.

This should inform any decision on how you sequence the commands. The other specification documents on the site are also helpful to ensure your implementation is conforming.

You would probably save yourself several person-months by using an existing open implementation. There are a number described at [*Modbus Technical Resources*](http://www.modbus.org/tech.php).

Comment: I need to send request from master to multiple save for function 3 which is read multiple bytes.

Comment: In that case I will get the response from the slave which may take time to respond. So How to handle such scenario?

Comment: Either concatenate the multiple requests into a single contiguous read, or queue the subsequent requests and send them after the initial response is received.